# Can a HTML color picker remember the selected color?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm using a color picker to enable the user to choose a background color. I've implemented that and it works fine, but the problem is that when the user clicks the color picker for a second time, the color picker resets. It doesn't 'remember' what they selected before, essentially.

My code is:

```
<label className='optionSelectors'>BACKGROUND COLOR: </label><br/>
<input type='color' value='#FFFFFF' onChange={this.handleBgColorChange}/>
```

So when the user clicks the color picker the first time, it defaults to white. Say the user picks purple, but then on reflection they want to go a shade lighter or darker, so they open the color picker again - it goes back to white.

I also tried removing the `value='#FFFFFF` attribute but it still just defaults to white?

Edit: I am using React and the function handleBgColorChange() is as follows:

```
handleBgColorChange(e) {
  document.getElementById('Collage').style.backgroundColor = e.target.value
}
```

The relevant input just sits within vanilla HTML, it's not part of a complex render or anything fancy. The code is literally:

```
<div>
  <label className='optionSelectors'>BACKGROUND COLOR: </label><br/>
  <input type='color' value='#FFFFFF' onChange={this.handleBgColorChange}/>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#tracking_color_changes Might be useful, listen for changes to color then update the value based on the selected color

Comment: Please put executable code

Comment: Can't reproduce. Unless you reload the page, the color is the last selected color of the input. Just as it is with an ordinary text input for example.

Comment: Also please tag the framework you use for `{this.handleBgColorChange}`

Comment: Edited to reflect

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components

And use controlled in most cases. For example:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#FFFFFF');
  const handleBgColorChange = useCallback(({ target: { value } }) => {
    setColor(value);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <label>BACKGROUND COLOR:</label>&nbsp;
      <input type='color' value={color} onChange={handleBgColorChange} />
      <hr />
      <div class="collage" style={{ backgroundColor: color }}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m9z1dajh/